# Unboxing Instances of Different Types with a Generic Type Parameter that Implements an Interface

Tags: .net, generics, f#

I am working on an abstraction for a variation on a key-value store style API where I have the following interfaces (simplified for clarity).

```
type IValue =
    abstract member Id: int64

type IKey<'value when 'value :> IValue> = interface end

type IKeyGenerator<'value, 'key when 'value :> IValue and 'key :> IKey<'value>> =
    abstract member Generate: 'value -> 'key

type IKeyValueStore<'value when 'value :> IValue> =
    abstract member Store: 'value -> unit
    abstract member Get: int64 -> 'value option
    abstract member Find<'key when 'key :> IKey<'value>> : 'key -> 'value option
```

Basically, each value can be looked up by multiple keys, and the keys for each value are generated by `IKeyGenerator`s.  When I call `Store` on the `IKeyValueStore`, I want to find all the key generators for the given value, run each of them, and store each key for the value so it can then be retrieved by any of those keys.

My problem is that, while I can reflectively discover all implementations of `IKeyGenerator` that have a `'value` type parameter that matches the `'value` type for this `IKeyValueStore`, I can't safely unbox them to a consistent type.  I tried unboxing them all to `IKeyGenerator<'value, IKey<'value>>`, but this doesn't work if the concrete implementations don't explicitly implement the interface that way.  If they implement the interface referring to a specific implementation of `IKey`, the unboxing fails.

I then tried introducing a simplified `IKeyGenerator<'value>` interface that defined the `Generate` method as simply returning `IKey<'value>` instead of `'key :> IKey<'value>`, which solves the problem with unboxing all the implementations, but I then run into problems downstream with not knowing the actual type of the key (for example, in order to do the `Find` when there are multiple possible keys for this value).

Is there some way I can safely obtain a list of `IKeyGenerator` instances for different `IKey` implementations, provided that they all implement `IKey<'value>` for the same type of value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a two-tier implementation of the key generators: a base class that implements `IKeyGenerator`, but itself has more concrete type parameters, constrained in the way you have there:

```
type IKeyGenerator<'value when 'value :> IValue> =
    abstract member Generate: 'value -> IKey<'value>

[<AbstractClass>]
type KeyGeneratorBase<'value, 'key when 'value :> IValue and 'key :> IKey<'value>> =
    abstract member Generate: 'value -> 'key

    interface IKeyGenerator<'value> with
        override this.Generate v = this.Generate v :> _
```

Then have specific implementations inherit from `KeyGeneratorBase`.

This way, the implementations can have their concrete types to work with, and the consumer will have the narrow types that it expects.

Or, alternatively (and I much prefer this way), have a function to create `IKeyGenerator`s:

```
let mkKeyGenerator<'value, 'key when 'value :> IValue and 'key :> IKey<'value>> (gen : 'value -> 'key) = 
    { new IKeyGenerator<_> with 
        member this.Generate v = gen v :> _
    }
```

---

P.S. I know this is not what you asked for, but I must warn against excessive use of reflection and classes. This never ends well. Consider a more functional, idiomatic approach.

Comment: I ended up going with a variation of the second solution here, where I just tag a function of `'value -> 'key` with an attribute and then do the interface generation dynamically when I find that attribute.  I think this will satisfy my OO consumers while making it idiomatic for F# users as well.